# Allow insertion with special characters in database using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to allow $(dollar) ,(comma) and .(full stop) into database by converting from string to decimal.Below is the way i need to insert into database.But with my current code it is inserting as given below

```
                        decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
                        drNew[i] = d;
                        i++;
```

Comment: What do you mean? you can just use a varchar datatype and insert it as string

Comment: So you are having issues converting to decimal? because your question is stating something else.

Comment: That's not a "problem". Currency values are usually saved as Number.

Comment: @abc please do not store `$25,529.98` in the database. It will give you more headaches then advantages. store them as decimal and then format it during retrieval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to convert from a string with currency symbol to decimal:

```
var num = decimal.Parse("$25,529.98", NumberStyles.Currency);
```

You may also pass the culture if you need/want:

```
var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
var num = decimal.Parse("$25,529.98", NumberStyles.Currency, cultureInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is backwards and not advisable. Have a [hidden field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield(v=vs.110).aspx) that stores the numeric value and a label that displays the formatted string in currency format. Then save the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
int number = 1234567890;
Convert.ToDecimal(number).ToString("#,##0.00");
```

You will get the result `1,234,567,890.00.`

Comment: add convert.tostring() or convert.toint64()

Comment: number.ToString("N"); try this one

Comment: decimal numericValue = 3494309432324.00m;
string formatted = numericValue.ToString("#,##0.00");

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/jquery/1076/using-jquery-add-commmas-numbers-textbox....just go through it this will help you

Comment: then you easly gets the formatted string from textbox directly